# org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.openPdfFile throwing NullPointerException in Linux server

Tags: java, jpedal

I am trying to open the pdf file which has an image, so I want to display pdf file in AWT window, openPdfFile method and other methods which are provided for opening the pdf file like openPdfFileFromURL, openPdfFileFromInputStream are used from jpedal_lgpl.jar file.

It's working fine in windows, After I deploy the class file in linux server it throwing the following exception:

```
Exception:at org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.openPdfFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.openPdfFileFromURL(Unknown Source)
```

please tell me jpedal_lgpl.jar is the supported jar or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL valid/working? Does it open from a browser?